# karate.scenario.executorName is always 'undefined' in karate logs

Tags: spring-boot, logging, karate

I couldnot find any info of karate.scenario.executorName in karate docs. Can I know where should I use?

or

How can I log the name of a scenario which has called the current scenario.

Answer (score 0):

See if these help:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77156823/143475
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73075056/143475

Else consider what you are asking for as not supported. You are welcome to contribute code.