# Seeing afterScenario hook running after @setup scenario

Tags: karate

Currently we have a call to output a link to our splunk (reporting system) based on a value in the response, or header, but this is also being ran after the @setup function.  Is this expected functionality or should the @setup be excluded from running hooks (before or after)?

afterFeature call

```
* karate.configure('afterScenario', function(){ karate.call('classpath:adapters/splunklink.feature'); })
```

@setup call

```
  @setup
  Scenario: Define endpoint for common negative tests
    * def endpointFile = read('_v1endpoints_Goldberg.json')
```

output as shown in report output
[image]

Comment: quite likely karate needs changes to not run hooks for `@setup`, for now you may be able to use info in the context, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77613020/143475